# What is the VB.NET equivalent of passing 'this' in a method signature in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, this

My question stems from the code samples from Wrox Press's Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns.  The code downloads are in C#, however, I'm working through the samples in VB.

I would appreciate if someone could explain what 'this' means in the following method signature, and what the equivalent method signature would be in VB.NET.

Here is the code sample (from p.51) in question:

`public static void Apply(this IList<Product> products, IDiscountStrategy discountStrategy) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an extension method. The this indicates that you can call the static method with the following syntax:

```
  products.Apply(strategy);
```

as opposed to to

```
  WhateverClass.Apply(products, strategy);
```

In VB you would decorate the method with the `Extension` attribute

```
  <Extension()>
  Sub Apply(ByVal products as IList<Product>, ByVal discountStrategy as IStrategy)
    ...
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx for more

Comment: 8 seconds before me, and almost exactly the same. great minds think alike.

Comment: Thanks.  I accepted your answer as the MSDN link points to the VB.NET version of the solution (opposed to the C# implementation), and was posted just before John's.

Comment: One difference with vb.net extension methods is that they can accept the first parameter as a `ByRef`.  This can sometimes be useful with structures, though unfortunately vb.net will allow the use of such methods on read-only structures (a silly construct that will usually generate bogus code).  C# will not allow extension methods' `this` parameter to be declared as `ref`, nor does it allow any way I can find to invoke a vb.net extension method with a `ref` parameter for `this`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) they are implemented in [VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

The syntax you need is:

```
<Extension()> 
Public Sub Print(ByVal aString As String)
    Console.WriteLine(aString)
End Sub
```

for example

Answer (score 3):

For an extension method in VB you use the [`ExtensionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx)

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub Apply(IList(of Product) products, IDiscountStrategy discountStrategy)
    '...
End Sub
```

The above syntax may not be 100%

Answer (score 0):

I think it's for extension methods. Not sure how those are implemented in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

the `this` used thusly denotes an extension method.  you now have an `Apply` method that can be used on any `IList<Product>` as if it were a member method, so you can call it like

```
list.Apply(discountStrategy);
```

instead of like

```
Apply(list, discountStrategy);
```

Its really useful to avoid having to name that method `ApplyDiscountStrategyToListOfProducts`, and having tons of `Apply*ToListOf*` methods.

The VB equivalent is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx